# Can you use the database on a website for android?

Tags: android, django

I'm developing an app and a website simultaneously. The website will be done in django and using Google' app engine, so therefore Google's database. IS there anyway i can download and use the database for an android app? Preferably I would like it to download and make it available offline to the users.

Comment: definitely be able to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a REST api like django tastypie on the server side, and consume the rest resources for the models you need with your android app. After you get the Json/xml messages on your android just save it to the local sqllite db

Answer (score 0):

Android does provide a SQLite interface for you to read and write to a local db.  You could fetch the db through a web request and save it locally, yes.  Being on Google App Engine does not help / hinder your ability to do this.